# Sprig boot error : Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

i write my simple project in SpringBoot and use Hibernate. I have three entity but when I start my application I have this error :

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.entity.User.tasks[javafx.concurrent.Task]**

And this is my code:

```
package com.example.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id

    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

TASK :

```
package com.example.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String date;

    @NotEmpty
    private String startTime;

    private String stopTime;

    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMIAL")
    private User user;

}
```

USER:

```
package com.example.entity;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMAIL", referencedColumnName = "email")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_NAME", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

And pom.xml dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, missing @Entity annotation has created the issue. Once added, Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

In `User` , you are importing the wrong `Task` class .

Just remove `import javafx.concurrent.Task;` (you don't need to import `com.example.entity.Task` instead, since your three classes are in the same package).

Note that the error message gives a good hint about this :

> targeting an unmapped class:
>   com.example.entity.User.tasks[**javafx.concurrent.Task**]